# vba vlookup using selection box

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use a lookup formula where the lookup value is based on a selection box. Please see the code below:

```
Sub Vlookup()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select a cell", Type:=8)
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLookup(rng, tblstaff.xlsm!Rng, 2, False)"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert your **Range** into a **String** holding the address:

```
Sub Vlookup()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select a cell", Type:=8)
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLookup(" & rng.Address(0, 0) & ",G3:J100, 2, False)"
End Sub
```